# Android Augmented Reality with camera input and a cardinal point

Tags: java, android, android-studio, augmented-reality

I'm developing an app with Android Studio for geolocalize an object in motion with the reports of multiple users.

I send a notification to users neighbors that they may see the object.

I would like to implement a simple fragment with the Augmented Reality with the camera input and a arrow positioned in the cardinal point (or coordinates) from where the object was last seen.

This is to help the user, that receives notification, to know where to get the object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was SDK by Metaio(http://metaio.com/) but was purchased by Apple. It has some kind of Radar view, where you would see image that camera takes on your display, but when you would spin around you, you would also see all the POIs in the vicinity of your position. Similar SDK is also offered by www.wikitude.com/

In Metaio, you could get closest POI and it's relative position to screen. So you could probably do the same with Wikitude. If POI would be left of the screen, you would just create arrow pointing left.
But you would also have to add API, which would get POI's GPS location from other users and send it to others.

Here is the list of SDKs and there comparison: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks

It's just basic info, but I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I see that Metaio was purchased by Apple. Wikitude have a free trial but there is a watermark.

Comment: There are probably also some other SDK's which have similar features. But I don't know any that would be completely free.

Comment: @pedrodj46 I have added SDK list to my post, so that you will have easier time finding right SDK for you.